# Aggregate function in Kohana Jelly ORM

Tags: php, kohana, jelly

could you help me to find out how to insert aggregate function using Kohana - Jelly module?

I.E. i need to show result of following query :

```
SELECT COUNT('total_item') AS tot FROM items WHERE category_id = '1'
```

really appreciate your help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
$count = Jelly::select('item')->where('category', '=', 1)->count();
```

This would generate this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `items` WHERE `category_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

from briefly looking at the documentation.  It's going to be something like

```
$cnt = Jelly::select("tot")->select("count('total_item') AS total")
       ->where("category_id","=", 1)
       ->limit(1)
       ->execute();

echo $cnt->total;
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

i m using following with kohana 3.1

> $count = ORM::factory('items')->select(array('COUNT("id")',
>   'total_items'))->find_all();